# Regarding get automatic columns in sql`

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have basically 50 fields in a table and I want to select this fields from table on a regular basis.

**Problem is**: I have to write all this 50 fields manually.

Is there any shortcut in intellisence or any other tool where I can get all fields. automatically by pressing tool.

Also guys if anyone knows here extra addons on sql..then please post it here.

Comment: can you explain more detail what you want ?

Comment: ok lets say i have 10 columns named :- empid,empname,empsalary,empaddress,empdogname,empmothername,empfathername..etc etc..... Now instead of this query select * from emp...I want sql to automatically write down field name ie..select empid,empname,.... , from emptable...is any way to do this...I hope now u will get it

Comment: I think you have mis-tagged this question, should only be tagged with one of `mysql`, `sql-server-2005`,`sql-server-2008`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/download.html link.
It may help you. 
Its a great intellisense tool for sql. Its has all functionality to improve productivity.

Comment: Note the *convert * to columns* feature is only in the $99 version

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party here (answer already accepted) but here goes anyway...

Did you know that you can drag the columns from the table to the editor window in Sql Server management studio?

So to get the columns, you can expand the table in SSMS, click on the `Columns` *item* (for lack of a better word) and drag it to the editor window. When you release, a comma separated list of all the columns for the table will be inserted to the editor at the position you point to.

It's not a easy as autoexpanding `*`, but it's a good little trick when you have lots of columns.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select name+',' from sys.columns where object_id=OBJECT_ID('tablename')
```

Now you just need to copy the result and put after the select keyword